# Lua pattern parentheses and 0 or 1 occurrence

Tags: regex, lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to match a string against a pattern, but there's one thing I haven't managed to figure out. In a regex I'd do this:

```
Strings:
en
eng
engl
engli
englis
english

Pattern:
^en(g(l(i(s(h?)?)?)?)?)?$
```

I want all strings to be a match.
In Lua pattern matching I can't get this to work.

Even a simpler example like this won't work:

```
Strings:
fly
flying

Pattern:
^fly(ing)?$
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't make match-groups optional (or repeat them) using Lua's quantifiers `?`, `*`, `+` and `-`.

In the pattern `(%d+)?`, the question mark "looses" its special meaning and will simply match the literal `?` as you can see by executing the following lines of code:

```
text = "a?"
first_match = text:match("((%w+)?)")
print(first_match)
```

which will print:

```
a?
```

AFAIK, the closest you can come in Lua would be to use the pattern:

```
^eng?l?i?s?h?$
```

which (of course) matches string like `"enh"`, `"enls"`, ... as well.

Comment: Sadly that kinda looses the meaning, since: `enlh` doesn't really suit. I'm going to have to workaround this by capturing the rest of the word `(%a*)` and then checking if it's an allowable 'suffix'. Thanks anyways :) and I already expected this, but thanks for confirming and saying that it matches the literal `?`

Answer (score 3):

In Lua, the parentheses are only used for capturing. They don't create atoms.

The closest you can get to the patterns you want is:

```
'^flyi?n?g?$'
'^en?g?l?i?s?h?$'
```

If you need the full power of a regular expression engine, there are bindings to common engines available for Lua. There's also LPeg, a library for creating [PEGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar), which comes with a regular expression engine as an example (not sure how powerful it is).